# jquery datatable ajax no data available mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a table that is made in the `$( document ).ready` function. I am also using the jQuery DataTables plugin. For some reason, when the page loads,ajax call  a controller and return data and set this my grid all taken data but although all data load into datatable, a row is taken and warn me as no data available, my code as shown below;

HTML :

```
<div class="ibox-content">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" id="summary-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductCode)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="SetInventoryList">                         
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#summary-table').DataTable({
            pageLength: 25,   
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'copy' },
                { extend: 'csv' },
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
                { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },

                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    customize: function (win) {
                        $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                        $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                        $(win.document.body).find('table')
                            .addClass('compact')
                            .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                    }
                }
            ]

        });
        $("#summary-table").DataTable();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "GetInventoryList",
        mimeType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                var body = "<tr>";
                body += "<td>" + data.ProductCode + "</td>";
                body += "<td>" + data.ProductName + "</td>";
                body += "<td>" + data.Description + "</td>";
                body += "</tr>";
                $("#summary-table tbody").append(body);
            });

            $("#summary-table").DataTable();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetInventoryList()
    {
        IEnumerable<ProductBO> model = productBLL.GetAll().AsEnumerable();
        var model1 = from m in model select new { m.ProductId,m.ProductCode, m.ProductName, m.Description };
        return Json(model1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your Datatable is loaded there is no Data so Datatbel adds a row saying "No data available in Table.

But when you do ajax call you are appending Data in existing table.

So it will just append below above code

To resolve this empty tbody first and then append

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "GetInventoryList",
        mimeType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Empty tbody
            $("#summary-table tbody").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                var body = "<tr>";
                body += "<td>" + data.ProductCode + "</td>";
                body += "<td>" + data.ProductName + "</td>";
                body += "<td>" + data.Description + "</td>";
                body += "</tr>";
                $("#summary-table tbody").append(body);
            });

            $("#summary-table").DataTable();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Fail!');
        }
    });
```

**Edit 1**

Ideally I will not use datatable the way you are using.

I will combine ajax and datatable initialisation together and let datatable do dirty work.

Something like this

```
$("#summary-table").DataTable({
  "processing": false,
  "serverSide": false,
  "paging": true,
  "destroy": true,
   pageLength: 25,   
   buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'csv' },
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },

        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                    .addClass('compact')
                    .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }
    ],
   dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
  "columns": [
        { "data": "ProductCode" },
        { "data": "ProductName" },
        { "data": "Description" }                           
  ],
  "ajax": {
      "url": "GetInventoryList",
      "type": "GET",
      "dataSrc": "[]",

  }
});
```

Comment: Make sure to still pass all your options into the DataTable() plugin

Comment: Hi Ashish, thank for your help. now i didnt take no data available but i cant use datatable properties like paging and sorting and other etc. i think i am wrong in something when datatable is append body.

Comment: Updated my answer